# With '7-day Unlimited MetroCard' in NY do I have to wait 18 minutes to transfer from one line to another?

Tags: trains, public-transport, buses, new-york-city

Let's say during my trip I have to make a transfer from one line to another. According to the Google search I did, I found that in most of the stations where multiple lines are interconnected, we can transfer from one line to another just by walking within the station.

But what if we have to walk out and get into a another line? Google maps shows intermediate walking between lines for some destinations. So if I do that will it cost me again?

And 7-day Unlimited MetroCard description [here](http://www.freetoursbyfoot.com/how-to-buy-a-new-york-city-subway-pass/) says that we must wait 18 minutes before using again. Also it states that "unlimited transfers, including between buses and subways".

I'm a bit confused here. For buses you have to get down from one have to get into another. So aren't we suppose to swipe the card again? How did this transfers work? What does it means unlimited transfers?

Is this is same for Pay-Per-Ride MetroCards as well? Although it clearly states that "free, Subway to subway transfers included within the system". Again it states this "free subway-bus and bus-bus transfers within 2 hours".

Would appreciate a clarification from someone who has experienced this before.

Comment: It's 18 min **at the same station**.  You always have to swipe/dip but with an Unlimited card, it doesn't really matter if you 'transferring' since it's included anyway.  The 2 hours window only applies to PPR cards since you only pay for 1 'trip' which can include both bus and subway.

Answer (score 25):

No.  The 18 minute limit applies only in the same station.  You can use the card in any other station as soon as you are able to get there.

The most common related problem encountered by tourists is getting in on the wrong side of a station where you can't cross from one side to the other without leaving the station.  Then they are at the mercy of the station agent's kindness to let them through the service gate.

I'm not sure how it works on the bus if you want to get back on the same line after doing a quick errand, but certainly if you're transferring to a different line you will have no problem.

Source: personal experience.

Comment: So will it cost me for each and every transfer a $2.75(which is the standard price/ride as of today)?

Comment: @Mad unlimited ride metrocards just give you unlimited rides, that's all. There's no "money" on them, there's just a time limit - the card stops working after a week.

Comment: @Bahrom: It sounds like you need two of them to get _actually_ unlimited travel.

Comment: @HenningMakholm hahah, well it's to prevent a group of people from just buying a single card and (ab)using it.

Comment: @Bahrom Also to discourage the selling of swipes.

Comment: ...yeah, tourists. Definitely never happened to a New York native like me... (the 86 St. & Lex. station has nailed me like that more than once, I’m embarrassed to admit)

Comment: If that really is an issue, then why don't they treat those as multiple stations? The only purpose for the limitation I can imagine is preventing multiple users to use the same card in sequence. Which would not be an issue on different sides of the same station, would it?!

Comment: @hmakholmleftoverMonica You _absolutely_ don't need two cards (unless you are two different people). How often do you go _in_ to the same station twice in 18 minutes? Note that you _leave_ stations without swiping your card, so you could get out of one station, do a five minute errand, and go back into the same station no problem!

Comment: @hmakholmleftoverMonica The 18 minutes is only a problem when I enter on the wrong side (as noted) or when I enter a station, realize I forgot something in my apartment, and have to run back to get it. Even then, as long as there is a person at the booth, they will always let you in if you talk to them and swipe your card.

Answer (score 5):

For Unlimited metrocards, you do not have to wait to transfer from one line to another and you do not get charged - it gives you unlimited rides. 18 minute rule does not apply ***unless*** you're using the metrocard ***in the same station*** or ***on the same bus line*** (*even if you are getting on a different bus - I once missed my stop, so I just decided to get on another bus going in the opposite direction, but my metrocard didn't work, showing that it was "Just used"*).

For Pay Per Ride metrocards, you can transfer ***once*** for free ***within 2 hours*** of the initial swipe in the following cases: **Bus to Train**, **Train to Bus**, **Bus to Bus** (different lines, see my experience above), and **Train to Train** (more on this below). You insert/swipe the card the 2nd time anyway, but it doesn't get charged.

For **Train-Train** transfers you can either:

- Transfer within the station - these are free and you don't need to swipe again. Almost all the major lines are interconnected and you rarely have to walk outside in order to transfer.
- Transfer outside of the station (usually paid, free ones labeled [here](http://web.mta.info/nyct/maps/subway_map.pdf) as *"Free out of subway system transfer"*) - if it's a free transfer, the conductor announces it on the train (so for Lexington Ave. / 59th St., "*A free transfer is also available to 4, 5, and 6 trains by walking to the Lexington Ave. 59th St. station and using your metrocard*").

Comment: It's an unlimited ride metro card.  There's no additional charge for additional rides.

Comment: @phoog, you're right, I'll update to reflect that it only applies for pay per ride.

Comment: If you can hear anything the conductor says on the train, you are way ahead of me.

Comment: @Kevin the automated messages play back loud and clear on newer messages. I should have clarified that lol

Comment: Just noticed I had said 'on newer messages' - I meant on newer trains.